# picasso - load image into imagebutton in adapter

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, picasso

I want to load an image into a `ImageButton` in an adapter, this is sometimes not working... I have a adapter with 4 entries, and sometimes, the button image is just loaded 2 times instead of 4 times. Always only on the first creation of the adapter... After screen rotation or so, everything works fine... But on the first display, it does not work correctly...

The adapter with 4 rows calls 2 times prepare and two times loaded on the first creation only...

Following is my adapter's `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_link, parent, false);

    convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_pos, position);

    ImageView iconRow = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.icon);
    final ImageButton btOpen = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.btOpen);

    // this NEVER fails
    PicassoTools.getPicasso().load(item.getIconResId()).into(iconRow);
    // this sometimes (at the first start) does not work reliable
    PicassoTools.getPicasso().load(isAutoLinked ? R.drawable.linked : R.drawable.unlinked).into(new Target()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable d)
        {
            L.d(this, "BUTTON PREPARE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap b, LoadedFrom loadedFrom)
        {
            L.d(this, "BUTTON LOADED");
            btLink.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable d)
        {
            L.d(this, "BUTTON FAILED");
            btLink.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

My PicassoTools function (I have some extra functions in this class):

```
public static Picasso getPicasso()
{
    if (picasso == null)
        picasso = new Picasso.Builder(MainApp.getAppContext()).memoryCache(getCache()).build();
    return picasso;
}
```

Comment: can you please post full adapter code and where you initialize btLink in getView() ?

Comment: Do you really have to use Picasso? Because I have a good solution without using Picasso.

Comment: I have an image based application and therefore (because I still get some OOM errors) try to use the cache everywhere where possible... anyway, the already given answer was the solution... Just did not think about this little detail anymore..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Target

```
private Target loadtarget;
```

Write this code in getView()

```
if (loadtarget == null)
    loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {

        }
    };

try {
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    iae.printStackTrace();
}

public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(b);
    imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(bdrawable);
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: now that you say, I've already read that months ago... that target does only work with an explicit object... I just couldn't remeber that, until now... thanks, I will try and check that out

Comment: sure... only one thing, in an adapter I can not do it the way you proposed... I now just create the `Target` object and set it as a tag of the button... and then check this tag to get the corresponding `Target` object...